# C++: Is it bad to use global variables that are pointers to instantiations of single-instance-only classes?

Tags: c++, global-variables

In my program, I've got a bunch of classes that will only ever have one created instance for the duration of the program. They are created only once on initialization, and destroyed only once on closing.

These classes all tend to present really broad functionality that is used by many different parts of the program, and so having them as global externs is really clean and easy to understand, rather than encapsulating them in another class or passing around pointers.

The program is multi-threaded, and all of these classes contain their own mutex for access.

Are there any problems with this approach? If so, what are the recommended alternatives.

Comment: Initialization of the pointers: Does it happen in singlethreaded mode or under a lock?

Comment: I assume that global variables are pointers that are initialized at the beginning and are destroyed at the end? I don't see any problem with such approach.

Comment: Yes, the initialization all happens in the beginning in single-threaded mode, and the global variables are all pointers.

Comment: @Nantucket: The problem happens if these global variables try to use each other from their constructors.  If foo trys to use bar, than bar might not be constructed yet - and it will crash.  By using singleton pattern in my answer it fixes this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a singleton pattern as follows:

```
Foo& foo() { static Foo x; return x; }
```

This is completely thread-safe. See here: [G++ 4.6 -std=gnu++0x: Static Local Variable Constructor Call Timing and Thread Safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533649/g-4-6-std-gnu0x-static-local-variable-constructor-call-timing-and-thread-s)

It is guaranteed by the current standard.

Furthermore this is superior to static initialized global variables because if you have multiple of the above they will be initialized lazily in the correct dependency order.

```
Foo& foo() { static Foo x; return x; }

Bar& bar() { static Bar x; return x; }
```

and in Bar::Bar there is a call to foo(), then the Foo singleton will be created before Bar.

If I had of used global variables:

```
// Foo.cpp
Foo foo;

// Bar.cpp
Bar bar;
```

No such ordering is guaranteed.

#### 3.6.2 Initialization of non-local variables

> ...the initialization of a variable is indeterminately sequenced with respect to the initialization of a variable defined in a different translation unit....

Comment: When you say "No such ordering is guaranteed", it feels a bit misleading to me. An ordering _is_ guaranteed.

Comment: OK, but you put `Foo foo; Bar bar;` in the same code block in your examples so I assumed you meant them to live in the same source file and hence TU.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Your comment is incorrect, across translation units there are many cases where ordering is indeterminate.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Ok ive added comments to indicate they are in different translation units.

Comment: and why is it better than simple global variable? :) thread - safe? have you ever tried to implement thread - safe singleton in C++?

Comment: @innochenti: It is better than global variable for the reasons explained in my answer (ordering).  The constructors of the singletons can use each other without breaking.  The above local static variable singleton pattern __is__ thread-safe, read the linked question/answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Singleton, but be sure of thread safety. For a tutorial, take a look at [SINGLETON PATTERN - 1. THREAD SAFETY](http://www.oaklib.org/docs/oak/singleton.html)

An example would be

```
static SomeSingleton* getInstance()
{
    lock_mutex();
    if(!pInstance_)
        pInstance_ = new SomeSingleton();
    unlock_mutex();
    return pInstance_;
}
```

Comment: This is not necessary.  The current standard guarantees that local static variables have such guard.  See my answer.  Furthermore your pattern causes a leak,  destructor will never be called.

Comment: That is assuming he is using C++ 11, which not everyone is using yet, the question is not tagged as, and he does not mention.

Comment: C++11 is the current standard.  Furthermore all current compilers support this anyway, even before C++11.

Answer (score 0):

By using global variables in your classes you make them difficult to test. Their behaviour now depends on a global state, which makes it difficult to reason about them. One class depends on the global variable. Another class depends on it, too. Both can change the state of the global variable any time. In essence you have a created a mutual dependency between both classes. With every access to the global variable you are one step closer to one version of the dependency hell.

You have mentioned that you do not want to pass them around as pointers. Actually I would prefer that method. By explicitly passing a dependency (your global variables) to a method or constructor you tell the world about it. If you need to pass ten dependencies to your method, you might want to rethink your solution. It might be a lot of work, but helps to improve the architecture of your program.

You have written that your classes "tend to present really broad functionality". This might be an indicator that they should be broken down into smaller components, so that you only have to pass around the functionality that you actually need.

My advice is that

- you should avoid using global variables, especially in the form of singletons
- try to find out more about [dependency injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) to properly pass around your dependencies
- watch video [Don't look for things](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0) (Clean Code Talks, Misko Hevery)

Answer (score -1):

c++ has big problems with order of calling global objects constructors
somebody calls it "global initialization fiasco"
It's not related with multithreading, but related with initialization
If your program has many global objects then it may cause some problems (of course there are some methods to solve that problem)

You can use pattern 'singleton' but I'm not sure will it be useful in your case

Comment: By using the pattern shown in my answer, the order is guaranteed to occur in dependency order.

Comment: Oh thanks. When "Foo& foo()" became signleton?? thread-safe for one compiler doesn't mean anything on others

Comment: Foo& foo() returns a reference to a singleton local static variable that has static storage duration and is constructed on the first call to foo() in a thread-safe way.  Google for "C++ local static variable".  The thread-safety is guaranteed by current standard.

Comment: author nothing said about c++11. IDoes this mean that no one uses c++98 and your solution is only right?

Comment: He said C++ and the 2011 version is the current standard - but its not like its a new feature, all compilers support this anyway and have for many years.

Comment: "all compilers support this anyway and have for many years". Thread-safe? Oh I want find that place in c++98 standard

Comment: You know of a current C++ compiler that doesn't put thread-safe guards around local static variables?  All the major ones I know certainly do.

Comment: c++11 guarantees only thread-safe initialization for static variables, author says about thread-safe access for variables. How c++11 can help in this case? Or it guarantees also thread-safe access?

Comment: No the guards around local statics just protect initialization.  Shared object access cannot be efficiently protected by compiler or runtime, and must be done manually with synchronization methods such as queues, mutexes, semaphores, lock-free data structures, etc.